# BASH extglob negate not working as I expect

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose I have the following dir structure

```
./testdir
./testdir/a.c
./testdir/b.c
./testdir/testdir2/
./testdir/t.tar
```

and suppose my CWD is testdir and I want to echo all directory entries that don't have a .tar extension.

This works:

```
echo *.!(tar)
```

However, I expected this to produce the same result but it does not:

```
echo *!(tar)
```

Only the period is missing from the 2nd command. That 2nd echo command lists the d.tar file. The asterisk glob character should match all characters and the extglob negate should list anything that does not end with tar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with these files:

```
$ ls
a.b  b.c  testdir2  t.tar
```

This matches all files that have a period but do not have `tar` following the period:

```
$ echo *.!(tar)
a.b b.c
```

This matches all files that do not end with `tar`:

```
$ echo !(*tar)
a.b b.c testdir2
```

This is the extglob that surprises but shouldn't:

```
$ echo *!(tar)
a.b b.c testdir2 t.tar
```

The `*` itself can match anything, such as `t.tar`.  Since it is not necessary to add `tar` after `t.tar`, this is a match.

Comment: This answer helps. It's easy to mistakenly think of the asterisk glob character in the same way as * used in some Regex rule sets. Lesson here: don't confuse Regex * and BASH *. They are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` and `!(tar)` bits aren't complementary globbed sets that are intersected.

They form a single glob that must expand.

I'm guessing `t.tar` matches for something like `t.tar` matches `*` and "" matches `!(tar)`.

The glob you want is `!(*tar)`. Anything that *doesn't* match the `*tar` glob.

Comment: this answer was the most useful one for me, it was such an obvious mistake not using !(*word) instead of !(word)...I would have accepted this one if it were up to me